# react native TouchableOpacity, different functions by first and second click

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, text-to-speech, touchableopacity

I'm creating a simple text-to-speech function for my react native app.
I have a button, when you click it for the first time, it will read the text and play the sound.
But I want to make it dynamic. For example: If you click again it should stop, if click again, should play again, etc.....
But now, it is only available for playing the sound with any click.
Where/how should I execute the stopReadText()?
I still don't have any idea about this. Thanks a lot.

Here is the code:

```
const readText = () => {
    Speech.speak('text')
  }

const stopReadText = () => {
    Speech.stop()
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress=(readText)>
        <Divider style={styles.modalDivider} />
        <Image
          style={styles.speaker}
          source={require('../../assets/speaker.png')}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
```

(I am using expo-speech)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by taking on a boolean state variable:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const [isPlay,setIsPlay]=useState(false)

const readText = () => {
    Speech.speak('text')
  }

const stopReadText = () => {
    Speech.stop()
  }

const handlePlay =() =>{
  if(!setIsPlay){
      readText()
      setIsPlay(true)
  }
  else {
      stopReadText()
      setIsPlay(false)
  }

 }


  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePlay}>
        <Divider style={styles.modalDivider} />
        <Image
          style={styles.speaker}
          source={require('../../assets/speaker.png')}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried a similar one but had a too-many-rerender error. But I will try yours once more

Comment: You can do it this way, there should be no issue. let me know it works or not.